# On CentOS - how to maintain custom changes after packages get upgraded

Tags: linux, centos, cron, package-management

I have this applied to my centos 7.6 system

chmod o+rwx /var/spool/cron

(please no hint on that this might not be a good idea) The system is only used for having tomcat runnning a web application - no user login at all.

If at some time in the future I do upgrade the system using package manager

- will the access rights be changed back to original rights?
- can I tell the system to apply again the access rights I have given (In a way that i dont have to bother later)?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the access rights be changed back to original rights?

Only if the file `/var/spool/cron` is included in the new upgrade (something has changed). Otherwise it will not be changed.

> Can I tell the system to apply again the access rights I have given (In a way that i dont have to bother later)?

Unfortunately you can't do that easily, there is no functionality for that in the CentOS package manager (or at least not to my knowledge).

You have a few possibilities here:

**1.** Create a cron that checks the yum update history, and if that specific package has been updated, run the command `chmod o+rwx /var/spool/cron`. Even if the permissions have not been reset, using this command will pose no problem.
**2.** Create your own bash function to update that *specific* package and run the command afterward (and save that function to `.bashrc`).
**3.** Do it manually. Why should this actually be a problem? You'll be doing the upgrade manually, and this is just one command. If the commands become more, just create a script and call that script every single time after an upgrade.